# How to make xterm erase shift+backspace?

Tags: xterm, stty

I know that if I want to make xterm erase a character when I press backspace, I do:
`stty erase ^?` but I also want xterm to erase a character when I press shift+backspace, and I can't find an explanation for how to do this.

With a little C program using ncurses, I have determined that when I press shift+backspace, it translates to the following sequence of bytes:

`27 91 51 59 50 126`

When I press ctrl-v and then shift+backspace, it shows up in xterm as:

`^[[3;2~` (where ^[ is, of course, the escape character, ASCII byte 27).

I have tried doing `stty erase` followed by ctrl-v, shift+backspace but I get the following result:

```
 ~ > stty erase ^[[3;2~
stty: invalid integer argument `\033[3'
Try `stty --help' for more information.
2~: Command not found.
```

Is there a way to do this? Or is it impossible because shift+backspace is not a single byte but 6?

Comment: try `xterm -xrm '*VT100*translations: #override Shift <Key>BackSpace:string(\1
77)'`, and if it works, make that xrm argument loaded by xrdb in each session (usually by adding it to `~/.Xresources`, though that's not guaranteed to work on all desktops)

Comment: `stty` can only "bind" single bytes, not escapes like `^[[3;2~`, and cannot bind multiple bytes to the same action.

Comment: I tried that `xterm -xrm ...` command, but it doesn't perform a backspace when I do shift+backspace. However, it also doesn't echo `2~`, which was the current behavior; it just nothing. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: copy-pasto, my bad, sorry; a space has slipped between the `\1` and the `77` of `\177` (same as 0x7f `^?`). Corrected command: `xterm -xrm '*VT100*translations: #override Shift <Key>BackSpace:string(\177)'`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As [pizdelect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/313992/pizdelect) pointed out in a comment:

`xterm -xrm '*VT100*translations: #override Shift <Key>BackSpace:string(\177)'`

Put this into `~/.Xresources` to have it loaded by xrdb for each session.